# Calling SVG Sprites with Ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

I'm trying to call different external SVG sprites in a single HTML page. If I stick to one, everything works perfectly, as soon as I want to call different SVG sprites I end up with only one loading. So basically, it loads only one sprite and ignores the others. Am I missing something in the syntax here?

I'm using the following ajax code // I'm a newbie, so I'm sure I'm making a terrible mistake here :)

```
<script>
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "sprite1", "sprite2", "sprite3", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onload = function(e) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

Then in HTML
I'm using this

```
<svg class="sprite1">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-name"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm possibly not the best source but the issue maybe that it loads them in chunks try `e.ondata()` in the onload function to see if in that you can get all of them.

Comment: @Scurgery How do you wanna write it? `ajax.onload = function(e.ondata()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using the answer for this but it is a bit longer code.

```js
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "sprite1", "sprite2", "sprite3", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onload = function(e) {
  e.ondata = (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk);
  }
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
  document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
```

It is but a flying thought, but might work.

Comment: Thanks, man! unfortunately, I tried it and it shows the same thing, loads sprite 1 elements but ignores the two other sprites.

Comment: Sorry bro :( ... An other thought...are you sure that you can use open to load multiple stuff at the same time? I never used it in this way.

Comment: Thanks, man, no idea really! I'm no expert here :D hopefully, the community will help with this issue.